# Not able to change state properties of redux reducer in function call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this redux reducer case, which has multiple conditions to work with. I am getting issue in changing value of state properties.

//code explaination:
In the second condition I am checking if action.hoverIndex > action.dragIndex, and if the condition is true then it creates "td" variable to hold the new state. After state change I have to make some changes in the properties of the state.

In the else part of the 2nd condition when I change the properties of "td" by assigning new value in for loop, it works as expected, but same thing when I try in "nestedConditionHandler" it does not work. not sure what is causing this issue.

```
const cmdArray = [
 "ECommand",
 "BCommand",
 "CCommand",
 "DCommand",
];

const cmdPair = {
  ECommand: "EndE",
  BCommand: "EndB",
  CCommand: "EndC",
  DCommand: "EndD",
  };

const notFirstCommand = [
 "PCommand",
 "QCommand",
 "XCommand"
 ];

 case actionTypes.UPDATE_COMMAND_WORKFLOW:
  // Deep clone of current state
  const temp = cloneDeep(state);
  // Draged command state
  const dragCard = temp[action.dragIndex];
  const tempDragCard = cloneDeep(dragCard);
  // hovered command state
  const hoverCard = temp[action.hoverIndex];
  const tempHoverCard = cloneDeep(hoverCard);
  
  //condition one
  if (
    action.hoverIndex === 0 &&
    notFirstCommand.includes(dragCard.class_name)
  ) {
    return temp;
  }

    //condition 2
    // command drag from top to bottom

    if (action.hoverIndex > action.dragIndex) {
      const td = update(temp, {
        $splice: [
          [action.dragIndex, 1],
          [action.hoverIndex, 0, tempDragCard],
        ],
      });

      let startIndex;
      let endconditionIndex;
      // for nested commands
      const nestedConditionHandler = (i, currState) => {
        startIndex = i + 1;
        
        endconditionIndex = td.indexOf(
          td.find((cur) => cmdPair[currState.class_name] === cur.class_name)
        );
        
       
        while (startIndex < endconditionIndex) {
          const tempTd = td[startIndex];
          console.log(tempTd);
          console.log(currState.indent + 1);
          td[startIndex].indent = currState.indent +1
          td[startIndex].parentId = currState.parentId
          
          if (cmdArray.includes(td[startIndex].class_name)) {
            nestedConditionHandler(startIndex, td[startIndex]);
          }

          startIndex += 1;
        }
      };

      if (
        dragCard.class_name === "ECommand" ||
        dragCard.class_name === "EfCommand"
      ) {
        for (let i = action.dragIndex; i < action.hoverIndex; i++) {
          td[i].indent = dragCard.indent + 1;
          td[i].parentId = dragCard.parentId;
        }
      } else {
        for (let i = action.dragIndex; i < action.hoverIndex; i++) {
          td[i].indent = dragCard.indent;
          td[i].parentId = dragCard.parentId;
          if (cmdArray.includes(td[i].class_name)) {
            nestedConditionHandler(i, td[i]);
            
          }
        }
      }

      return td;
    }

    // command drag from bottom to top , next condition
```

Comment: Deep clones make my soul hurt.  Either [do it properly](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects) or use [an immutability helper](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#immutable-update-utility-libraries).

Comment: It looks like the `$splice` syntax that you are using is from the [immutability-helper package](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) (formerly [react-addons-update](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html)) so I'm not sure why you would use an immutability package *and also* make deep copies.

Comment: Sorry if I leave a million comments, I'm going through this bit by bit because I don't see the problem immediately.  Instead of `td.indexOf( td.find(` just do [`td.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

Comment: I can't tell what `nestedConditionHandler` is supposed to be doing or what it means for a command to be nested.  The variable `cmdPair` is not defined here (nor is `notFirstCommand`).

Comment: @LindaPaiste, I have updated the code, with cmdPair  and notFirstCommand , nestedConditionHandler is used here to recursively update state if condition is true. here I am trying to do same as in else part, not sure what should be the correct way, logically i thought this should work.